# Where is this file?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Please help find these file.
All instructions have this:

iOS
Add this line to your **ios/Podfile file**, then run pod install.

end
Android
Add the following lines to **android/settings.gradle**:

where is this File?

Comment: and also MainApplication.java

Answer (score 0):

According to Google, `The Podfile is located in the root of the Pods project. An easy way to open it is via "Open Quickly" (Shift Cmd O) typing Podfile. If it's been added to the project, you can just click on it. Otherwise, open it using the File menu or drag its icon on top of Xcode's`